# ¿ValueMember y DisplayMember en ComboBox de Java?

Tags: java

Tengo un `JComboBox` en Java, donde muestro un listado de empleados, resultado de un Query, este lo almaceno en un ResultSet y lo quiero es que cuando sea seleccionado, tome el ID y no el nombre, a diferencia de C#, Java no tiene una herramienta como `DisplayMember` o `ValueMember` que me permita de una manera fácil mostrar un Texto y a la hora de seleccionarlo que tome el valor, el método donde asigno el resultSet a mi combo es el siguiente:

```
while(rs.next())
            {
                fila = new Object[colNo];
                for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
                {
                    fila[i] = rs.getObject(i+1);
                    employeesCombo.addItem(fila[i]);
                }   
            }
```

Mi pregunta es ¿Cual es la manera mas fácil para poder hacerlo? Ya que si muestra los datos, mas no de la manera que quiero, soy nuevo en Java, así que no estoy tan familiarizado.
Esta es la forma en que se muestran, primero muestra el ID y luego el nombre del empleado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque vas en la dirección adecuada te matizo algunas cosas:

En java todos los objetos extienden de *Object* pero existen tipos primitivos, y sus clases wraper, de tal forma que es un poco antinatural crear una clase pojo como lo has hecho tu, más natural seria algo así:

```
public class Employee {
  public int id;
  public String name;

  public Employee(int id,String name) {
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id=id;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name=name;
  }

  //Esto es lo que hace que el JComboBox se visualize correctamente
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return id + " " + name;
  } 

}
```

Esto te permite tener una clase empleado con métodos para acceder a sus atributos. Básicamente es la clase que mapea el resultado de tu ResultSet

Recorer el ResultSet y utilizar los métodos especificos que posee en función del tipo para obtener los valores que necesitas para crear objetos empleado:

```
while(rs.next()) {
  Employee empleado=new Employee(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2));
  employeesCombo.addItem(empleado);
}
```

Espero que te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo mi propia pregunta, lo que hice al final fue crear una clase, donde añado los datos, fila por fila del Objeto que tiene todos los resultados, tomo el valor real y el metodo String regresa el valor a mostrar:

```
public class DisplayEmployeeList 
{
    public Object displayMember;
    public Object valueMember;

    public DisplayEmployeeList(Object display,Object value)
    {
        displayMember=display;
        valueMember=value;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return displayMember.toString();
    }
}
```

Y finalmente, en el método principal donde añado cada valor, los añado al objeto que creo de la clase durante un while, y añado el item al JCombo.

```
while(rs.next())
            {
                fila = new Object[colNo];
                for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
                {
                    fila[i] = rs.getObject(i+1);
                }
                emp = new DisplayEmployeeList(fila[1], fila[0]);
                employeesCombo.addItem(emp);
            }
            con.close();
```